# Linux kernel syscall return not given pointer

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, userspace

I am trying to implement a new syscall as an experiment, but I always get a segfault. I think the problem is that I try to return a pointer to a char array that is not in the user space.
I tried to allocate the memory in the user space by using the GFP_USER as flag for kmalloc, but the problem remains the same.

This is how I call my syscall and I can't change it at the moment (normally would allocate memory for return and provide it as parameter):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/mysyscall.h>

main() {
  printf("Returned: %s\n", mycall("user string arg"));

}
```

The definition of the syscall function looks like this:

```
#include <linux/mysyscall.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>

asmlinkage char* sys_mycall (char * str_in) {
    int size = 0;

    printk(KERN_INFO "Starting mycall.\n");
    size = strnlen_user(str_in, 255);
    printk(KERN_INFO "size = %d\n", size);
    char str[size];
    char *ret;
    ret = kmalloc(size, GFP_ATOMIC | GFP_USER); 

    if(str != NULL){
        copy_from_user(str, str_in, size);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Copied string.\n");
    }else{
        printk(KERN_ERR "str is NULL!!!\n");
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    // Doing operations on str

    int acc = access_ok(VERIFY_WRITE, ret, size);
    if(acc){
        printk(KERN_ERR "Not accessible!\n");
        return -EFAULT; 
    }

    int len = copy_to_user(ret, str, size);
    if(len){
        printk(KERN_ERR "Could not copy! len = %d\n", len);
        return -EFAULT;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I have tested it a lot and I'm sure the syscall is called correctly, but it has problems with `copy_to_user`. 
`copy_to_user` always returns a positive value (equal to size, so does not copy at all).
By the way the address of ret is like f74ce400 and str_in 080484ac.

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The destination of the copy should be a user space pointer, while the pointer `ret` is in Kernel space. You should have the destination pointer be provided from the user as an argument. See for example:

- [Source code example from "Linux kernel programming"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515227/source-code-example-from-linux-kernel-programming)

Comment: That's true. Nice find :) That was coming from trying around a lot. But unfortunately the segfault remains. I corrected my code in the question now.

Comment: OK, Edited the answer as well

Comment: That's totally true, but it is a requirement for me to not modify the syscall definition. So I try to allocate memory in behalf of the user.

Comment: Can you call the function with a pointer variable, having the input act as output (`char *input_p = "input"; mycall(input_p)`) ?

Comment: That would be an alternative, but unfortunately that is also not possible in this setting -.-

Answer (score 0):

You should do copy_from_user before , calling strlen(). Typically system calls gets an extra argument with length of the argument passed.

For ex; mysyscall(str,strlen)